# Calling third party REST API with curl in Java

Tags: java, curl

I want to call this curl command to get list of applicant names from Java in JSON

`curl -u uname:pass my_REST_Endpoint_provided_by_vendor`

here is my code:

`URL myURL = new URL("url");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(unamepass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    int code = conn.getResponseCode(); // 200 = HTTP_OK
    System.out.println("Response    (Code):" + code);
    System.out.println("Response (Message):" + conn.getResponseMessage());`

If I run this command on my command prompt it runs fine and gives me the output but if I run this code I get `Response    (Code):405
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL:`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that HTTP method was wrongly written in documentation provided to us. and it wasn't PUT it was GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an 405 error because you are using the HTTP Method PUT instead of GET, which is used by curl by default. Remove the line:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```